# Incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct node *' from type 'struct node'

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have written a code to insert a node in Singly Linked List. But it keeps giving me error:

**incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct node *' from type 'struct node'***

```
void insert(int d, int pos)
{
    int k=1;
    struct node *p,*q,*newNode;
    newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (newNode=NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate Memory");
        exit(0);
    }
    newNode->data = d;
    p = *head;
    if(pos == 1)
    {
        newNode->next=p;
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while((p!=NULL) && (k<pos))
        {
            k++;
            q=p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        q->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = p;
    }
}
```

It is giving me the same error on line:
`p = *head;`
and
`*head = newNode;`

This is `head`

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *head;
```

Any Solutions?

Comment: `p = head;` and `head = newnode;` ... maybe ... didn't read your code

Comment: Please show what `head` is.

Comment: ```struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;

}*head;```

Comment: ```p = head;``` and  ```head = newnode;``` doesnt make the code work.

Comment: Feel free to undo my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters in this if statement

```
if (newNode=NULL)
```

there must be comparison instead of the assignment

```
if ( newNode == NULL)
```

These assignments

```
p = *head;
```

or

```
*head = newNode;
```

are incorrect. It seems you mean

```
p = head;
```

or

```
head = newNode;
```

Also this if statement

```
if(pos == 1)
{
    newNode->next=p;
    *head = newNode;
}
```

should be changed like

```
if(pos == 1 || head == NULL )
{
    newNode->next=p;
    *head = newNode;
}
```

Pay attention to that the parameter that denotes the position should have an unsigned integer type. For example `size_t`. And positions should start from 0 instead of 1.

Also it is a bad idea when functions depend on a global variable such as in the case of your program when functions depend on the global pointer `head`.

Using your approach with the global pointer head I would write the function the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *head;

int insert( int d, size_t pos )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        struct node **current = &head;
        
        while ( *current != NULL && pos-- )
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
        
        new_node->data = d;
        new_node->next = *current;
        
        *current = new_node;
    }
    
    return success;
}

FILE * display( FILE *fp )
{
    for ( struct node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", current->data );
    }
        
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

int main( void )
{
    insert( 2, 10 );
    insert( 0, 0 );
    insert( 1, 1 );
    insert( 3, 3 );
    
    putc( '\n', display( stdout ) ); 
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
```

Comment: I tried removing the asterisk but then newnode isnt inserted.

Comment: @VanshChaudhary It is inserted.

Comment: can u create the find method as well...? @VladfromMoscow

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing the pointers while assigning them, which is causing your issue.

In `p = *head`, you *want* to assign `struct node *head` to `struct node *p`, but you are dereferencing head, meaning you are actually assigning `struct node head` to `struct node *p`. To fix this, do not use a `*` in the statement.

It is the same, but in reverse, when you do `*head = newNode`. You dereference head, meaning you are attempting to assign `struct node *newNode` to `struct node head`. This fix is the same as the previous one: leave out the `*`.